# How can I float an element on scroll, with delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following div floating but I want as the green element inside left panel to have a delay about half second.

Does anyone any idea how can I do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/eoopvgmc/22/

This is the code which is floating the elements on scroll

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var offset = $('.ads').offset().top, top;
        $(document).on('scroll', function() {
            top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset + 'px';
            $('.ads').css({
                'top': top
            });
        })
    });
```

Comment: do you only want to delay one side(left), rather than both sides?

Comment: I want to grab that `.element` and I want to make a delay with half second by its parent there could be 10 elements in left and 10 in right. I've created only one to understand what I want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get something like what you describe working by adding some transition effects to the element and using a little delay, you should be able to tweak the `timeout`, `margin-top` and `transition` values to get exactly what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = $('.ads').offset().top, top;
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset + 'px';
        $('.ads .element').css({
            'transition': 'none',
            'margin-top': '-60px'
        });
        $('.ads').css({
            'top': top
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.ads .element').css({
                'transition': 'margin-top 3s',
                'margin-top': '0'
            });
        });
    })
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yckszc16/

Comment: When you scroll up you see the element jump up to the top of the box, is there any way around this?

Answer (score 6):

To make the `.element` independent transition, you need to move it out of the `.left-zone` element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var offset = $('.ads').offset().top,
        top;
    $(document).on('scroll', function () {
        top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset;
        console.log(top);
        $('.ads').css({
            'top': top
        });
        $('.element').css({
            'top': +top + 50
        });
    })
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9ykh4Lep/)

Answer (score 4):

Since the element is absolute positioned, I took it that it does not need to be nested within the div. Therefore I changed the HTML from this:

```
<div class="left-zone ads">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div class="left-zone ads"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

I then adjusted the css to position the element in the same place as it was, like so:

```
.element{
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left: -71px;
width: 20px;
height: 30px;
background: green;
}
```

This allows the object to be manipulated completely seperately to the parent, which also makes it much more flexible in what you can do with it.

To get the animation going on it, I had to change a few bits of code.

Where you were setting the top variable, I removed the + 'px' at the end to allow for the setting of different values in each animation. This is required because the element must have it's top value (60px in this case) added to the animation to keep it in the correct position. I then copied the code that sets the animation going and repeated it for the 'element' div, and added the 60px to it. if that doesn't make sense then check out the code below.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
        top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset;
        $('.ads').css({
            'top': top + 'px'
        });
        $('.element').css({
            'top': top + 60 + 'px'
        });
    })
```

Next is to get the delay. I first tried the jquery .delay function but it didn't seem to work so I made an even simpler change, add the transition line from your 'ads' div to the 'element' div's css and change the duration to half a second longer. This achieves the required effect of it coming in afterwards! Here is the code:

```
.element{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  left: -71px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  transition: top 1.3s;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle if you want to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/hdn1oyjd/

Let me know if you have any questions!